# updated rom 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.4 now Getting Fatal Error on my magento site Class 'Zend_Cache_Backend_File' not found

Tags: zend-framework

updated rom 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.4 now Getting Fatal Error on my magento site Class 'Zend_Cache_Backend_File' not found also had numerous other files missing but cannot solve the Zend Cache Backend File issue

Comment: Do you have the file `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`? I have a feeling you left out some files while you were upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **disable the compiler** before and clear the cache after the upgrade?

Usually that is a post-install **compiler** error because the compiled files are the old version which are reacting against the new installation.

**Recompile** and reenable the compiler after clearing the Magento cache.

It can also be a permissions problem where files had their permissions get changed when the upgrade was done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cache was cleared 
here is the detail from the post upgrade log there are a number of delete errors

Checking dependencies of packages
Installing package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.5
Package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.5 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.5

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
....Installing package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Varien 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

.Checking dependencies of packages
......Installing package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.5
Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.5 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.5

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...........Installing package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...............Installing package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.2.4
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
..Package installed: 
 community Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...............Installing package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Magento 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
....................Installing package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Pelago 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
.....................Installing package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
...Package installed: 
 community Lib_Unserialize 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...........................Installing package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_IDNA2 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
......................................................
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files:

/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/Web.config
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/bin/add-environment-

variables.cmd
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/bin/add-environment-

variables.ps1
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/bin/install-php.cmd
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/diagnostics.wadcfg
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/resources/WebPICmdLine/

Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/resources/WebPICmdLine/

Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.UI.dll
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/resources/WebPICmdLine/

Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.dll
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/resources/WebPICmdLine/

WebpiCmdLine.exe
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/PhpOnAzure.Web/resources/WebPICmdLine/

license.rtf
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./lib/Zend/Service/Win

dowsAzure/CommandLine/Scaffolders/DefaultScaffolder/resources/ServiceDefinition.csdef
Check permissions

Checking dependencies of packages
...................................................Installing package community/Lib_ZF_Locale

1.12.10.4
................Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.4 installed successfully
.Package installed: 
 community Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
..................................
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files:

/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./pkginfo/Mage_All_Lat

est.txt
Check permissions

Checking dependencies of packages
.......................................Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Default

1.9.2.4
.Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
..Package installed: 
 community Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
....................................Installing package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.4
Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
..Package installed: 
 community Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
.............................................Installing package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.2.4
.Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
....Package installed: 
 community Mage_Downloader 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
.........................................Installing package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.2.4
Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
....Package installed: 
 community Mage_Centinel 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...................................................
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files:

/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/multishipping/item/downloadable.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/creditmemo/downloadable.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/frontend/

base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
Check permissions

Checking dependencies of packages
................................................Installing package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers

1.9.2.4
.Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
.....Package installed: 
 community Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...............................................Installing package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.2.4
.Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
.....Package installed: 
 community Mage_Compiler 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
................................................................
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files:

/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/banner_rotator.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/catalog_android.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/catalog_hor_ipad.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/catalog_iphone.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/productinfo_iphone.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/tab_items_android.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/tab_items_ipad.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/design/adminhtml

/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/tab_items_iphone.phtml
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./skin/adminhtml/defau

lt/default/images/xmlconnect//mobile_preview/android/background_home_landscape.jpg
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./skin/adminhtml/defau

lt/default/images/xmlconnect//mobile_preview/android/bg_catalog_filters_shadow.png
Check permissions

Checking dependencies of packages
.................................................Installing package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
..Package installed: 
 community Lib_Cm 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache
..
Checking dependencies of packages
.....................................................Installing package community/Cm_RedisSession

1.9.2.4
Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
..Package installed: 
 community Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
............................................................................................Installi

ng package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.4
.............................Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
...Package installed: 
 community Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
....................................................................................................

..................................................
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to delete files:

/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/B

undle/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Composite/Fieldset/Options/Type/Checkbox.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

atalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

atalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

onfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Super/Collection.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

onfigurableSwatches/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

onfigurableSwatches/Model/System/Config/Source/Catalog/Product/Configattribute/Select.php
/kunden/homepages/14/d82414467/htdocs/InrhythmUK/MagentoDev/InRhythmeCommerce/./app/code/core/Mage/C

onfigurableSwatches/Model/System/Config/Source/Catalog/Product/Configattribute.php
Check permissions

Checking dependencies of packages
.....................................................................Installing package

community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.2.4
...........Package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
.....Package installed: 
 community Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

.Checking dependencies of packages
.............................................................................Installing package

community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.4
............Package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.4 installed successfully
....Package installed: 
 community Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
...................................................................Installing package

community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
....Package installed: 
 community Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
.........................................................................Installing package

community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.2.4
.Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
.....Package installed: 
 community Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
......................................................................................Installing

package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.2.4
...Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
.....Package installed: 
 community Lib_Mage 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache

.Checking dependencies of packages
...............................................................................Installing package

community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.4
Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community Lib_Credis 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache
.
Checking dependencies of packages
...............................................................................................Insta

lling package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.4
...Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.4 installed successfully
...
Exception during cache and session cleaning
Exception during cache and session cleaning
Exception during cache and session cleaning
Exception during cache and session cleaning
Exception during cache and session cleaning.Package installed: 
 community Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.4

Cleaning cache
..
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully.
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully...
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully.
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully
Cache cleaned successfully

Comment: Please move part of this to your original question post. This is not an answer.